# git rebase --continue no changes

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have two branches with two features: `banch_1` and `branch_2`.
`branch_2` uses feature from `branch_1`.
I've made changes in the `branch_1` and want to rebase `branch_2` on `branch_1` to get changes from `branch_1` into `branch_2`.

So, I'm checking out on branch_2:

```
git checkout branch_2
```

And trying to rebase on branch_1:

```
git rebase branch_1
```

After that I get 'Merge conflict' for two files. So I run

```
git mergetool -t meld
```

and resolving that conflicts, choosing changes from `branch_1`.

I'm saving files and going to terminal, typing 
`git status` and see that there is no changes in git index. Next I run `git rebase --continue` and getting

```
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
```

error. But there is nothing to add!
I type `git log` and see commit from `branch_1` but there is no commit from `branch_2`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did the mergetool step create a commit? When I do a rebase, I just stage a resolved conflict (using `git add`),  but do not create a commit. In your case a `git rebase --skip` might help?

Comment: It would help some output after each step, and the git status output after the merge.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when you're getting the merge conflict, you're accepting all the changes from `branch_1`, meaning that that particular commit from `branch_2` is irrelevant - any changes in that commit are identical to the incoming changes from `branch_1`.

When git is saying

> No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?

it's telling you that the commit you're trying to apply doesn't make any changes to the repo, and therefore there's no reason for it to exist.

The simple solution to that is `git rebase --skip`, which just says "ignore this commit and move on" as suggested in @C-Otto's comment. This will skip the commit you're currently dealing with, and move on to subsequent ones.

You might also find it easier to use interactive rebasing (`git rebase -i`), which first presents you with a list of the commits it will apply, and gives you various options for what to do with each individual commit. In this case, if you identify a commit that is no longer relevant, you can skip it up-front, so you'll never see the conflict in the first place.

Comment: I have done exactly this and this misses commits